# Autosar Vector Configurator Validation error on 'Mem_Infls'

Tags: vector, autosar, xmlconfigurator

I am setting BSW module 'Mem_Infls' on vector configurator.

When I execute validation check, it fails and shows an error.

And it is as below

---

### ERROR 23-10-25,23:15:52 (1803) Invalid XPath-expression for Attribute "RANGE" of node "/AUTOSAR/TOP-LEVEL-PACKAGES/ActiveEcuC/ELEMENTS/Mem/MemInstance/MemInstance/MemSectorBatch/MemSectorBatch/MemStartAddress": (1806) The XPath-expression "                                                         node:when(                                                             contains( node:fallback( ../MemPhysicalSector, ' ' ), 'DATA' ) = 'true',                                                             . = num:hextoint( ecu:get('Mem.InFls.DFlashBaseAddr') ) + ( num:hextoint( ecu:get('Mem.InFls.DFlashSectorSize') ) * ( substring-after(node:fallback( ../MemPhysicalSector, ' ' ), '_S') ) ),                                                             . = num:hextoint( ecu:get('Mem.InFls.PFlashBaseAddr') ) + ( num:hextoint( ecu:get('Mem.InFls.PFlashSectorSize') ) * ( substring-after(node:fallback( ../MemPhysicalSector, ' ' ), '_S') ) )                                                         )" caused an error: (35010) The requested ECU resource property "Mem.InFls.DFlashBaseAddr" does not exist

It seems parameter 'Mem.InFls.DFlashBaseAddr' is wrong or missing.

But there's not parameter on configurator as below picture

anyone knows how to fix this error?

[image]